# Future and Scala: Data type mismatch

Tags: scala, future

I have the next code:

```
package controllers.usersPage

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import model.{User, Users, Patients, CObject}
import scala.concurrent.Future

import service.{UserService}

class allUsersToJSON() extends Controller {

def convertUsersToJsonOrig(lusers: Seq[User]): JsValue = {Json.toJson(
                                               lusers.map { u => Map("id" -> u.id, "firstName" -> u.firstName, "lastName" -> u.lastName, "email" -> u.email, "username" -> u.username, "password" -> u.password)}) }


def retAllUsers = Action { request =>
   Ok( Json.stringify(convertUsersToJsonOrig(Users.listAll)))
  }
}
```

But, I am getting the next error:

```
$ compile
[info] Compiling 69 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to 
H:\project\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] H:\project\app\controllers\usersPage\retrieveAllUsersJSON.scala:29: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[model.User]]
[error]  required: Seq[model.User]
[error]      Ok( Json.stringify(convertUsersToJsonOrig(Users.listAll)))
[error]                                                      ^
[warn] Class com.sun.tools.xjc.Options not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] one warning found
[error] one error found
[error] (root/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Apr 17, 2017 10:51:11 AM
```

The instruction  Users.listAll is an Future one that will give me a list of User objects that I will need to convert to JSon. As I see this command gives me  the scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[model.User]]  data type. How can I do to get the Seq[model.user] from this command so I can use it within convertUsersToJsonOrig?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here for handling futures with play: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAsync

```
def retAllUsers = Action.async { request =>
  for {
    users <- Users.listAll
  } yield Ok( Json.stringify(convertUsersToJsonOrig(users)))
}
```

`Action` takes a `Request => Result`. While `Action.async` takes a `Request => Future[Result]`. This allows you to transform the contents of a future (using map, flatMap, and/or a for-comprehension) into a `Result` and give it to the framework to deal with.

Comment: I needed to add:
  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

after that all worked very well!! Thanks